# Afnetworking success/failure completion block not involved

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, macos, afnetworking

I tried to use afnetworking for a simple testing, but it seemed that the success/failure blcok was not triggered at all, is there anything I forgot to set up?

My code is below:

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {

    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@weather.php?format=json", BaseURLString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Succeed!");

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Fail");

    }];
    [operation start];
}
return 0;
}
```

Updated: I tried use a loop a to wait the operation to execute and print out, but nothing was printed out. Here is my updated version

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
@autoreleasepool {

    __block bool result = false;



    NSString *string = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@weather.php?format=json", BaseURLString];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:string];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

    AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
    operation.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

    [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSLog(@"Succeed!");
        result = true;

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

        NSLog(@"Fail");
        result = true;
    }];

    [operation start];

    while (1) {
        if (result) {
            break;
        }
    }


}
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes they will not be called because the program exits out before the operation even starts.

The main function returns 0 and the program ends and the operation have still not started.

You need to read more on asynchronous blocks.

Answer (score 0):

A common and simple approach to solve this problem (having an async function and a continuation) in a console test app would leveraging a semaphore which you wait on in the main function before you exit and release it in the continuation, which runs on some other thread. Now, the main thread will be blocked when waiting on the semaphore up until the semaphore gets released when the continuation has been run. Quite simple.

If you want to try out AFN in an console application, however, this does not work. You need to use a [run loop](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Multithreading/RunLoopManagement/RunLoopManagement.html) which adds some undesired complexity in order to get this simple test app to run. This is unfortunate, and stems from the simple fact that AFN executes its continuations on the *main* thread. IMHO, this is is a very bad design decision, which can lead to dead locks (as it would happen in your case) and is also less efficient.

So, your approach would use a RunLoop where you basically loop and check a flag for the condition "done" which is set by the continuation (the completion blocks). Since you are reading an writing the flag on the main thread only, you don't get a data race - that is, it should be thread safe.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your tips! I have tried to use a loop as you mentioned, still nothing printed out, I have updated the new version of my code in the post. Could take a look on that?